# Display GeoTIFF image in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to display a TIFF image in the ol map. To do this, I have to convert the TIFF to PNG.
I'm using [geotiffjs](https://geotiffjs.github.io/) to read the metadata and [plotty](https://github.com/santilland/plotty) to convert it to canvas and then to PNG.

It works somehow, but the colors are messed up. I got my TIFF file from QGIS (OpenStreetMap), I just selected a random area.

This is how it should look like:
[image]

And this is the result I get:
[image]

This is my code so far:

Read metadata from tiff file (I'm doing this in the Back-End)

```
const tiff = await geotiff.fromArrayBuffer(file.buffer);

const image = await tiff.getImage();
const geoKeys = image.getGeoKeys();
const bands = await image.readRasters();
const width = image.getWidth();
const height = image.getHeight();
const bbox = image.getBoundingBox();

return {
    projection: geoKeys.ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey,
    height: height,
    width: width,
    bbox: bbox,
    bands: bands,
    maxValue: bands[0].reduce((prev:number,next:number) => prev<next ? next : prev),
    minValue: bands[0].reduce((prev: number, next: number) => prev>next ? next : prev),
};
```

Front-End:

```
...get tiffData from server...

const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

const plot = new plotty.plot({
    canvas: newCanvas,
    data: tiffData.bands[0],
    width: tiffData.width,
    height: tiffData.height,
    domain: [tiffData.minValue, tiffData.maxValue],
    clampLow: true,
    clampHigh: true,
    colorScale: 'earth'
});
plot.render();

const dataURL = newCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

..add new ImageLayer...

source: new Static({
    url: dataURL,
    imageExtent: tiffData.bbox,
}),
```

I got my example code from here: https://pbabik.github.io/webraster/

I'm not sure if I need plotty for this, I would prefer to remove this library as I do not really understand what it does exactly. Does anyone know why my colors are wrong or a different solution to display TIFFs in OpenLayers?

Comment: I would say problem is in `colorScale` option. Try some other scale.

Comment: I know there are some different but I can't figure it out. If I don't set a colorScale my map becomes yellow.

Comment: If you look at Plotty docs at https://github.com/santilland/plotty, there are 27 different color scales possible. Did you try some of them?

Comment: not yet but I don't undestand why I should set colors if all I want is to get the colors from the original tiff imge

Comment: You do not need plotty, just copy the rgb data from the geotiff to a canvas and then create a data url https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-7435e

Comment: @Mike You should put this into answer. Very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need plotty, just copy the rgb data from the geotiff to a canvas and then create a data url:

```
let width, height, extent;

fetch("data/image.tif")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer();
  })
  .then(function (arrayBuffer) {
    return fromArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer);
  })
  .then(function (tiff) {
    return tiff.getImage();
  })
  .then(function (image) {
    width = image.getWidth();
    height = image.getHeight();
    extent = image.getBoundingBox();
    return image.readRGB();
  })
  .then(function (rgb) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    const rgba = data.data;
    let j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rgb.length; i += 3) {
      rgba[j] = rgb[i];
      rgba[j + 1] = rgb[i + 1];
      rgba[j + 2] = rgb[i + 2];
      rgba[j + 3] = 255;
      j += 4;
    }
    context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);

    map.addLayer(
      new ImageLayer({
        source: new Static({
          url: canvas.toDataURL(),
          projection: "EPSG:27700",
          imageExtent: extent
        })
      })
    );
  });
```

Working example (using promises instead of await) https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-7435e

Comment: I added more OpenLayers relevant code from working example